# An Efficient Minimum Distance Bipartite Matching Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, matching-theory

For one of my works, I need a "minimum distance bipartite matching" algorithm, which I describe below:

I have two disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ with $|A| = |B| = n$. The sets $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d \geq 1$ and I want to match each point $a$ in $A$ to a unique point $m(a)$ in $B$ (so $m$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$). I then want to solve the following minimization problem:
$$\arg \min_{m:A \mapsto B, ~\mathrm{bijection}} \sum_{a\in A}||a-m(a)||_2~,$$ where $||\cdot||_2$ denotes the $L^2$ norm.

My question is, is there an efficient algorithm to do this, other than the naive way of checking through all the $n!$ many permutations? If so, is there an inbuilt code in MATLAB or R which does exactly this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [minimum (equivalently maximum) weight bipartite matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_weighted_bipartite_graphs) where the weight of edge $am(a)$ is $||a-m(a)||_2$. An example of code to solve this is [here](https://github.com/rdmpage/maximum-weighted-bipartite-matching), although there will be various others, possibly in the languages you are looking for.